# valid triangle Harvard cs50 practice problem

Tags: c, function, integer, boolean, cs50

I am trying to create a program with a function that takes in three side lengths of a triangle and outputs if they create a valid triangle or not.

I keep getting this error:

```
comparison between pointer and integer ('bool (*)(int, int, int)' and 'int') [-Werror,-Wpointer-integer-compare]
    if(valid_triangle == true)
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~
```

This is my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool valid_triangle(int length_a, int length_b, int length_c);

int main(void)
{

    int length_a = get_int("side a: ");
    int legnth_b = get_int("side b: ");
    int legnth_c = get_int("side c: ");

    if(valid_triangle == true)
    {
        printf("This is a triangle\n");
    }
    else if(valid_triangle == false)
    {
        printf("This is not a triangle\n");
    }
}


bool valid_triangle(int length_a, int length_b, int length_c)
    {
        if(length_a <= 0 || length_b <= 0 || length_c <= 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(length_a + length_b < length_c || length_a + length_c < length_b || length_b + length_c < length_a)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: You will need to show us your code or better a reduced version. Please edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: "when I state the problem initially" That is not a useful description of your code and your problem. What do you try to do and what error do you get? Please add the exact and complete error message when you add the MCVE. But generally: yes, you must define (or at least declare) variables before you use them and they need to be of the correct type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

valid_triangle is a function so when you call it you need to pass in the parameters.  You also don't need to check for true and false since it must be one or the other.  Try this:

```
if(valid_triangle(length_a,length_b,length_c) == true)
{
    printf("This is a triangle\n");
}
else
{
    printf("This is not a triangle\n");
}
```